# How to make a formal text when there is a repeating letters in a word?

Tags: python, nltk

I have a function and inserted a new method in my code. I need to make a formal text that includes detection of repeated letters in a word

For example of the input text: Helllooooo. I don't know this.

Expected output: Hello. I do not know this.

This is my code for function:

```
import re
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
R_patterns = [
   (r'won\'t', 'will not'),
   (r'can\'t', 'cannot'),
   (r'i\'m', 'i am'),
   (r'(\w+)\'ll', '\g<1> will'),
   (r'(\w+)n\'t', '\g<1> not'),
   (r'(\w+)\'ve', '\g<1> have'),
   (r'(\w+)\'s', '\g<1> is'),
   (r'(\w+)\'re', '\g<1> are'),
]

class REReplacer(object):
    def __init__(self, patterns=R_patterns):
        self.patterns = [(re.compile(regex), repl) for (regex, repl) in patterns]

        self.repeat_regexp = re.compile(r'(\w*)(\w)\2(\w*)') #for not repeating letters in a word
        self.reple = r'\1\2\3' #for not repeating letters in a word

    def replace(self, text):
        s = text
        for (pattern, repl) in self.patterns:
            s = re.sub(pattern, repl, s)
        return s

        #for not repeating letters in a word 
        if wordnet.synsets(s): 
            return s
        repl_word = self.repeat_regexp.sub(self.reple, s)
        if repl_word != s:
            return self.replace(repl_word)
        else:
            return repl_word
```

The code for not repeating letters in a word is not working. I did make a comment in the part for not repeating letters.

Comment: Why would it not be "Helo"?  Why do the double Ls get to pass?

Comment: Because the word "Hello" is in the wordnet. There is no "Helo" in the wordnet

Answer (score 0):

This code iterate through all combination of repeat characters until it finds a word in wordnet. It does not use regex. See if it works:

```py
import itertools

def parse_word(word):
    if wordnet.synsets(word): 
            return word 

    chars = [word[0]]
    char_count = [1]
    for i in range(1, len(word)):
        if word[i] == chars[-1]:
            char_count[-1] += 1
        else:
            char_count.append(1)
            chars.append(word[i])
    char_count = [range(1, _ + 1) for _ in char_count]
     
    for repeat in list(itertools.product(*char_count)):
        word = ''.join([chars[i] * repeat[i] for i in range(len(chars))])
        print(word)
        if wordnet.synsets(word): 
            return word
```

Output:

```
>>> parse_word('helllooooo')
helo
heloo
helooo
heloooo
helooooo
hello
'hello'
```